# I am trying to export tcl buffer to bash variable

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I am trying to export tcl buffer to bash variable, i cannot get it to work.

I hope my example below will be clear of what i am trying to accomplish.

I definately would like an tcl embeded script

```
======================================
#!/bin/bash
var=bash_to_tcl

expect -c "

puts lindex $argv 0

expect "xx"
send "123\n"

set $var $expect_out(buffer) <<<< setting the variable to export to bash>>>>>>

}
exit 0
```

<<<>>
    =====================================

```
echo $var "tcl_to_bash"    (THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
=====================================
```

I have been searching all over for some clue of example but cannot find any.
I got the ecpect working but cannot export the output back to  bash

Answer (score 3):

The child process (expect) cannot alter the environment of the parent (bash). Usually information is passed between processes via the stdio channels:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is how bash captures the output of the expect program
var=$(expect -c '
    spawn ...
    expect "xx"
    send "123\n"
    # here is expect sending the info back to the parent
    puts $expect_out(buffer)  
')
do something with "$var"
```

Comment: The other way is to write it to a (known) file. That's a more complicated and messy (what happens if the script is run twice at the same time??) but makes it much easier to transfer many values. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Thank
I will play with both options and see how best to implement my final script.